# ios: How to obtain CLLocationCoordinate2D with <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

What is the propery way to obtain CLLocationCoordinate2D?

In .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

In .m

```
//Called when the location can be obtained
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    //Get the latitude and longitude location
    CLLocation *lastLocation = [locations lastObject];
    _latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", lastLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", lastLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Is it this:

```
_coordinate = lastLocation.coordinate;
```

or this:

```
_coordinate = manager.location.coordinate;
```

Comment: The first choice since that is the data you are getting from the delegate method.

Comment: Agreed. It's also the method prescribed by the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the documentation as already stated in the comments, because this is a must know for location programming. 
Second pay attention that is not the first data you get from delegate, because it could be a cached data (you need to check the timestamp) or an invalid data (with horizontal accuracy less that zero).
You could use that code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation * newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }
    NSTimeInterval interval = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(interval)>5) {
        return;
    }
   //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Hope this helps, Andrea